# How to deal with conundrum of `NullPointerException`?

Tags: java, spring, exception, nullpointerexception

Masking `NullPointerException` will give another delirium to developers as they are bombarded with logic that we are letting `Object` in memory pointing to `null` value. If we catch `NullPointerException` , we are again catching buggy code that takes `null` value. Ideally, we must stop object taking null input value in code, and being a valid code. I have seen `null` being passed as parameters in one of object created in code, and code successfully leads user go through activities. How is that possible.  Is it risky to implement such implementation which is against NullPointerException norms? As a fallback, we can't even use RuntimeException as it will mask `NullPointerException` from happening and we won't know buggy code was buggy at first place?

Comment: This is way too broad to answer in general. But as a guideline, they are generally the result of missing user input validation or coding errors.

Comment: Catching null dereferencing exception is usually a bad idea regardless of the platform/language. If your code allows null for some parameter then handle it explicitly. Otherwise, barring some buggy libraries or etc., just don't do it. Can't find a definitive reference for Java (https://www.quora.com/Is-it-bad-practice-to-catch-null-pointer-exceptions-in-Java), though.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a tag for Spring, I will share an example. It uses Springboot and Hibernate Validator though but just for information of one way of handling this case ..

http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services

Comment: Hi. I’m new to this website. May I please know why this is downvoted. As explained in my answer this was posted only for information as one example as to at what point null was handled not an actual answer.